# stored procedure returns result with 2 params only

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

hi guys below is my code

```
USE [arrestedpersonsdb]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[stnencodedtodisplay]    Script Date: 08/11/2013 11:18:32 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stnencodedtodisplay]
(
      @PageIndex INT = 1
      ,@PageSize INT = 10
      ,@RecordCount INT OUTPUT 
      ,@id int
      ,@fname varchar
      ,@lname varchar
    )
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
      (
            ORDER BY [fname] ASC
      )AS RowNumber
      ,[pid]
      ,[fname]
      ,[mname]
      ,[lname]
      ,[qualifier]
      ,[alias]

      INTO #Results
      FROM [todisplay]
      where (stnid = @id) and (type = 'STN')  and (fname = @fname or @fname = '') and (          lname = @lname or @lname = '')
      SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
      FROM #Results

      SELECT * FROM #Results
      WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

      DROP TABLE #Results
END
```

whats odd is that when the @fname and @lname is null it returns the expected result but when i try to pass a parameter on the @fname or @lname it returns nothing

sample below

```
USE [arrestedpersonsdb]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int,
        @RecordCount int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[stnencodedtodisplay]
        @PageIndex = 1,
        @PageSize = 10,
        @RecordCount = @RecordCount OUTPUT,
        @id = 1599,
        @fname = 'ALDRIN',
        @lname = ''

SELECT  @RecordCount as N'@RecordCount'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
enter code here
```

but when i pass the 'ALDRIN' as a parameter for the @fname it returns zero
is there something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Well, do you really **HAVE** a row with `fname` (first name) equal to `ALDRIN` ?? Seems to me like this would more likely be a `lname` (last name) - no??

Comment: yeah i do have..i made it work by omitting the other columns that is not related to the result

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified the size of the varchar parameters.

```
  ,@fname varchar
  ,@lname varchar
```

Not doing so will give you a size of one.

```
  ,@fname varchar(1)
  ,@lname varchar(1)
```

Change to whatever is appropriate in your case.

```
  ,@fname varchar(100)
  ,@lname varchar(100)
```

Comment: @fname varchar(50)
,@lname varchar(50) i set it to 50 still the same result

Comment: @angelogogo Are you sure there are rows in the table that match your where clause?

Comment: yes i tried it on management studio executing the query it returned 1 row..on the stored procedure if i dont pass any value on fname and lname all the rows that contains the id 1599 returns but passing additional value to the param fname of lname with the same id it returns zero

Comment: ALDRIN  DETABLAN MALABREG JR TUGUE 1 81 1599 STN nXOUBfAWYzssbzlaEclI here is the result on management studio id of 1599 and fname of ALDRIN

Comment: i manage to make it work i omitted from my view the additional results like 1 and 81 which stands for regid and ppoid i dont know the exact reason but it worked.thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

This might be a caps issue.  If so then the following would fix it:

```
(upper(fname) = upper(@fname) or @fname = '') and 
(upper(lname) = upper(@lname) or @lname = '')
```

or it could be a white space issue in which case the following would fix it

```
(rtrim(ltrim(fname)) = rtrim(ltrim(@fname)) or @fname = '') and 
(rtrim(ltrim(lname)) = rtrim(ltrim(@lname)) or @lname = '')
```

or both.

Comment: i tried both but still its not working il post the view that i am querying to be more clear

Comment: sadly i cant post it here because its too long but that is my only problem it wont return any result if i pass a value on fname or lname

Comment: @user2334366 - What happens when you do a select statement directly using SQL Management Studio?

Comment: i tried to omit the lname and tried using only the fname still it return nothing that is when i try to execute the sp. using sql managemet INTO #Results
      FROM [todisplay]
   where (stnid = 1599) and (type = 'STN') and (fname = 'ALDRIN') it says one row affected

Answer (score 0):

I might be late, but another optionto solve the issue is to try this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
  (
        ORDER BY [fname] ASC
  )AS RowNumber
  ,[pid]
  ,[fname]
  ,[mname]
  ,[lname]
  ,[qualifier]
  ,[alias]

  INTO #Results
  FROM [todisplay]
  where stnid = @id 
    and type = 'STN'  
    AND CASE WHEN  @fname =''
          THEN 'True' 
          ELSE fname 
            END  = CASE WHEN   @fname ='' 
                    THEN 'True' 
                    ELSE @fname 
            END 
    AND CASE WHEN  @lname =''
          THEN 'True' 
          ELSE lname 
            END  = CASE WHEN   @lname ='' 
                    THEN 'True' 
                    ELSE @lname 
            END
```

In your current try setting SET ANSI_NULLS OFF.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for the answer the answer il put it on my references